# How to start Logstash config-file

Tags: logstash

i have a problem with logstash when i want to start from my config file with the command"bin/logstash -f logstash-rt.conf"
this return:
Error: No config files found: logstash-rt.conf
Can you make sure this path is a logstash config file?
You may be interested in the '--configtest' flag which you can
use to validate logstash's configuration before you choose
to restart a running system.

can someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: do an `ls -al logstash-rt.conf` from the directory you are starting from.  Is the file there?  Does it have read permissions for the user you are starting logstash as?

Comment: thanks for your answer
i did it with the path to the file bin/logstash - user/username/folder/logstash-rt.conf
now i have a problem with pattern i want to find the response-time in my log 
you know how can i do it ?

Comment: Please post a new question, you can't ask multiple question in a single page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put config file in logstash folder and the path should be of the logstash folder when you execute the command
so bin/logstash is the relative path when you run it where the conf file is.

Answer (score 0):

Make a .config file and then paste it into the bin folder of Logstash and then use the below command in cmd to start it

logstash -f filename.config

Answer (score 0):

Below is the command to load logstash.conf

```
sudo bin/logstash -f apache.config --config.reload.automatic --path /etc/logstash/conf.d/filter.conf
```